# Push notification to consumer URL using amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Is there any option to push notification to consumer URL or SNS, when a message arrives in SQS queue.
Any option to avoid polling continuously from consumer

Comment: No. But you can setup event source mapping for lambda, and lambda will automatically pull sqs (without your involvement) for new messages and invoke your function.

Comment: Instead of sending the message to an Amazon SQS queue, you could instead send it to an Amazon SNS topic. Why is your current system using a queue? Does the message undergo further processing, or do you just want to send a notification?

Comment: Consumer processing capacity is less when compared to the producer. So we need to maintain queue. so SNS won't work in this case

Comment: @MuthukumarR if you use sns with http endpoints, you can customize its [delivery policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy) including throttling. So theoretically you could set up sns with http endpoint and tell sns to just deliver msg at a rate your customers can handle.

Comment: @Marcin, SNS will try for 3 tries, In case of a server is down or not able to handle load server might miss messages. There is no guaranteed ack

Comment: @Marciin, using Lambda is a good option. But it is difficult to maintain acknowledgment for guaranteed delivery to consumers

Comment: @MuthukumarR Lambda is the natural choice. But what is "acknowledgment for guaranteed delivery to consumers"?

Comment: @Marcin, we need to send a notification to RestAPI consumer and get a response of message received without any loss